# How to delete a treenode then select another to keep focus on the tree?

Tags: freepascal, lazarus

Surely I am overlooking something so obvious and simple here, but I just cannot see it.

I have a treeview, nodes are added to it at runtime and can also be deleted. When I delete a node, there is no longer a selected node in the tree, HideSelection is also set to False but that would make no difference anyway as the selected node is deleted, standard behavior I guess.

Anyway, to reduce the number of times and input required focusing back onto the treeview, I want to automatically reselect a node in the tree after one has been deleted (especially useful if deleting lots of nodes in quick succession as it removes the need to click back onto the treeview).

So lets say I have a tree like this:

[image]

This is the behavior pattern I am looking for, using the following scenarios as an example:

- `Item1` could be selected, when deleted `Root` becomes selected.
- `Item2` could be selected, when deleted `Item6` becomes selected.
- `Item3` could be selected, when deleted `Item4` becomes selected.
- `Item4` could be selected, when deleted `Item5` becomes selected.
- `Item5` could be selected, when deleted `Item4` becomes selected.
- `Item5` could be selected, when deleted if `Item4` is not present, then `Item3` should be selected.
- `Item5` could be selected, when deleted if `Item3` or `Item4` are not present, select `Item2`.
- `Item6` could be selected, when deleted `Item2` becomes selected.
- `Item7` could be selected, when deleted `Item6` becomes selected.

I keep getting Index out of bounds and other AV errors (in Lazarus) and that is without even getting to the point of checking where in the tree the current selected node is.

As it stands right now, in my Delete event I have this:

```
procedure TMainForm.actDeleteExecute(Sender: TObject);
var  
  SelNode: TTreeNode;
begin
  if TreeView1.Selected <> nil then
  begin
    SelNode := TreeView1.Selected;

    TreeView1.Selected.Delete;
    TreeView1.SetFocus;
    //ShowMessage(SelNode.GetPrev.Text);  
    TreeView1.Selected.Index := SelNode.Index; 
  end;
end;
```

Is this a case of me completely misunderstanding the situation again and making the task needlessly difficult, or is there a lot of work involved to implement such behavior?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: if the downvoter could make a comment on why my question is so bad I would really appreciate it if you think I can improve my question?

Comment: Save a reference to the node that needs to be selected before deleting the current node (based on the "behavior pattern"); delete the current selected node; select the Saved node: `TreeView1.Select(SavedNode)`.

Comment: BTW, in standard windows application (tested with D7), if the TreeView is already focused, and you would use a TSpeedButton that will not steal the focus from the TreeView, the selection is does automatically after you delete any selected node (I know nothing about lazzarus)...

Comment: Can I ask clarification as to the control that we are discussing. Is it the XE VCL `TTreeView`, or is it the Lazarus control?

Comment: Perhaps some of your difficulty is that your deletion behavior is inconsistent. If the first child of the root is deleted, the parent gets selected, but if the first child of a second-level node is deleted, its sibling gets selected instead. And if the second child of the root is deleted, the next sibling is selected instead of the root, but if the third child of the root is deleted, the *previous* sibling is selected. You're setting yourself up for confusion, both yours and your customers'.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan this would be the Treeview from the Lazarus controls. I actually thought they were the same as the Delphi ones, but I noticed some of the properties are different (`Treeview.Select`) for example is not present.

Comment: @RobKennedy confusion is my middle name, hence the amount of trouble and problems I get myself into, mostly caused by myself. I tend to overthink the simpler of tasks, and underestimate the more complex!

Comment: OK, I've re-tagged to make it clear what we are talking about.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan sorry for the confusion, my initial thought was they fell in the same category.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your mistake is to access the node, to get its index, that you've deleted: `SelNode` in your example. It's causing an AV.

Assuming your question is about the Lazarus's TreeView control (as mentioned in the question), you can follow Kobik's suggestion in the comments and find the node to be selected before you delete the item. Or, which I find simpler, you can implement your logic in the `OnDeletion` event of the TreeView. This event is fired just before the item is actually destroyed.

```
procedure TForm1.actDeleteExecute(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Assigned(TreeView1.Selected) then begin
    TreeView1.Selected.Delete;
    TreeView1.SetFocus;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.TreeView1Deletion(Sender: TObject; Node: TTreeNode);
begin
  if Assigned(TreeView1.Selected.GetPrevSibling) then
    TreeView1.Selected := TreeView1.Selected.GetPrevSibling
  else if Assigned(TreeView1.Selected.GetNextSibling) then
    TreeView1.Selected := TreeView1.Selected.GetNextSibling
  else if Assigned(TreeView1.Selected.GetPrev) then
    TreeView1.Selected := TreeView1.Selected.GetPrev
  else
    TreeView1.Selected := TreeView1.Selected.GetNext; // can be nil
end;
```

Note that I was unable to follow your logic regarding which item to select when one is deleted, primarily because when a node is deleted all of its children is deleted as well. You can adjust the above to suit your needs.

Comment: One thing I noticed is you use `if Assigned()` where I have been using `if TreeView1.Selected <> nil` - are they basically the same and just a cleaner way of writing it?

Comment: @Blobby - Yes, they're basically the same.